# module from jtv-apns gem not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, rubygems

I am using jtv-apns gem for push notifications to iOS : https://github.com/justintv/APNS

This gem is just one module APNS.

On two of my development machines, I have added the gem to my Gemfile and am able to require 'APNS' in a rails console, or in a file in lib/initializers

However when I push these changes to my server, I cannot access 'APNS', I get a `/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in 'require': cannot load such file -- APNSS (LoadError)`

All machines are running rails 3.2.3

I have tried uninstalling the gem and rebundling, and installing the gem via `gem install`.

Is there some reason that the module from the gem would not get loaded into my environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 2 development machines are Mac (UNIX) and my server is Ubuntu Linux.  The server for some reason required me to do `require 'apns'` requiring the module in lower case.